# Change the image of the search button cell in NSSearchField

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nssearchfield

I have a `NSToolbar` which contains a `NSSearchField`.

I have changed the image of the search button cell (in `awakeFromNib`) to one that more accurately describes what I am doing.

Unfortunately, if the user customises the toolbar the default image is restored.

How can I either
a) prevent Customisation, but still allow the user to select icons and/or text
b) detect the change, so I can restore the desired icon
c) change the image on the default

Answer (score 0):

Maybe b

Use NSToolbar Delegate and implement

```
- (NSToolbarItem *) toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar
      itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier
  willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag
```

There you could give back your custom Item.

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately this is never called - there is nothing that the user can actually add to the toolbar.

Comment: Strange. According to Apple this must be called. Did you connect the delegate either in Interface or code?